# Facing some issues with ReactJS first program

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I just started learning ReactJS, I am following this tutorials here. 
[egghead.io](https://egghead.io/courses/react-fundamentals) I just completed its first video and developed an app as shown in video, But some how I can see the html part but failed to load the dynamic content coming from the App.js Below is my code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  // always expected to return
  render() {
    return '<div><h4>Hello World of ReactJS</h4></div>'
  }
}
export default App;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ReactJS Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ReactJS First Project</h1>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render('<App/>' , document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "First application of ReactJS",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "AD",
  "license": "Apache",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: "./",
    fileName: "index.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would need some help to run it, not sure. I have installed everything as asked in the video, I am using node 6.2.2.

Comment: Any error in concole?

Comment: No error in console but I found a strange thing while npm start it says at the end 1 module hidden

Comment: Found an issue: http://localhost:3333/index.js not sure why it is happening but somehow index.js in not being built

Comment: The question does not formulate any concrete problem!

Comment: @YanFoto the problem is there, it is not reflecting the changes in the index.js, a file which is supposed to generate by babel is not being generated

Comment: You should formulate your problem precisely and mention exactly what works and what doesn't.

Comment: It is mentioned which you failed to understand, sorry but won't reply to you anymore

Comment: I found the solution, the code is fine, I just did "webpack main.js index.js" in terminal in the project directory, it generated "index.js" now I no longer get the 404 for index.js. Still I didn't figure out one thing is why webpack isn't running while I am starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.js`, change:

```
ReactDOM.render('<App/>' , document.getElementById('app'));
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The quotes are the problem. You want to render your imported component, not some String. Also I would be interested if you got a warning in the console.

Comment: I have tried this, in my IDE webstorm it is showing as an error so i put a ' around the <App /> tag. :(

Comment: Well I guess your IDE doesn't know what JSX is ;-) This may help: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/

Comment: Also this might help YOU understand JSX: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#your-first-component